# Double menu bar in Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

I just noticed a bug with the second menu bar in Stack Overflow Jobs, as well as in the *toast* notification (green) when I answered a message.

[image]

Comment: Okay, this is reproducible on Firefox Nightly 69.0a1. [Example URL](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/273047/onboard-spacecraft-software-developer-research-deutsches-zentrum-f%C3%BCr-luft?so=i&pg=1&offset=-1), then scroll down. The second menu bar is hidden by the first and should be 50px lower.

Comment: Also reproducible with OSX and Chrome 74.0.3729.169. On top of this, there seems to be a "how do you feel about this job listing" unicorn which also hovers over this second menu bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFHWx.png (for clarity I deleted the main menu bar with the dev tools HTML editor).

Comment: Also reproducible with Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Version 76.0.176.1 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows. Button takes me to https://www.dlr.de/dlr/jobs/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10596/1003_read-31226/ when I click @SebastianSimon's link.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox Stable 67.0 running on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). Has this been fixed?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to have been fixed:

[image]

It looks like it was just caused by a rogue Jobs banner with a low `z-index`. As you can see, the blue button in your screenshot is the same as the blue button in mine, so the banner was fixed.

IMO, the banner still seems a bit clunky - it has a weird open/close animation that doesn't quite go along with the rest of the page.

Comment: It's starting to feel like we might be better off _bringing back frames_. (Just make the element sticky and have a `z-index` higher than the sticky bar at the top, and the problem should be fixed without requiring any hacky JavaScript kludge like this one.)

Comment: Hey! SO Talent developer here. I can confirm that the menu bug has been fixed, it was indeed a problem with z-index. Thanks for reporting it @t3__rry! @connectyourcharger We'll take a look at the animation with the design team.

Comment: @Juan Thanks for the response!