# Issue in Stack Overflow jobs saved search alert

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design

When removing the saved search from Stack Overflow jobs, the alert message on success is showing incorrectly. More specifically, it is showing behind the navbar:

[image]

Environment:

Google Chrome   68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)

OS:Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus))

JavaScript: V8 6.8.275.24

The same is happening on Firefox v.67.0.1.

Comment: Related: [Double menu bar in Stack Overflow Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385853/4642212).