# Developer story warning overlay is partially blocked

Tags: bug, developer-story

[image: overlay bug]

As in the screenshot - this overlay appears on my profile, but is rather unreadable unless you open up developer tools.

Comment: Another one of those… [Completing survey on teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386145/4642212), [Issue in Stack Overflow jobs saved search alert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386022/4642212).