# Completing survey on teams

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-for-teams

When completing the teams survey I am redirected back to the site with a green div that pops underneath the main toolbar on top (where the search bar is, my user profile, my inbox, etc).

Not sure what this div said, maybe it thanked me for taking the survey?  I never could see what it said and then it vanished after like 10 seconds.  Its background color was green since I could see a green line under the main toolbar but the rest was hidden!

Comment: Related: [Issue in Stack Overflow jobs saved search alert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386022/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

We're unable to reproduce this exact issue, but it may be fixed when we resolved a related issue, [Double menu bar in Stack Overflow Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385853/double-menu-bar-in-stack-overflow-jobs).